# Length of half a circuit

Tags: calculus, integration

I was given to calculate the length of half a circuit with radious R (needless to say it is $\pi R$) as integral  in form of $\int ds$ where $ds=2\pi f(x)\sqrt{1-(f'(x))^2}$. I tried to simplify the integral and got $\int^R_{-R} \frac{ds}{2\pi f(x)}$, problem is I don't know how to convert between $f(x)$ and $ds$.

Comment: what is the function for "circuit"?

Comment: Circuit is not a function. The purpose was getting length of half-circuit which its function is $f(x)=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know the length of an infinitestimal arc in cartesian coordinates can be represented as
$$ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$$
and the constraint equation for circle with radius $R$ is given by
$$x^2+y^2=R^2$$
Since circle is in question it is much easier to work in polar coordinates where
$$x=r\cos(\theta)\rightarrow dx=\cos(\theta)dr-r\sin(\theta)d\theta$$
$$y=r\sin(\theta)\rightarrow dy=\sin(\theta)dr+r\cos(\theta)d\theta$$
Then the equation for arc length become
$$ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=\sqrt{\bigg(\cos(\theta)dr-r\sin(\theta)d\theta\bigg)^2+\bigg(\sin(\theta)dr+r\cos(\theta)d\theta\bigg)^2}$$
$$ds=\sqrt{dr^2+r^2d\theta^2}=d\theta\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{dr}{d \theta}\bigg)^2+r^2}$$
and the equation for constraint
$$x^2+y^2=\bigg(r\cos(\theta)\bigg)^2+\bigg(r\sin(\theta)\bigg)^2=r^2=R^2$$
By cosntraint equation we can see that $r^2$ is fixed as $R^2$. Replacing this in the arc length function
$$ds=d\theta\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{dr}{d \theta}\bigg)^2+r^2}=R\,d\theta$$
and the length for half circle
$$\int_0^{\pi}ds=\int_0^{\pi}R\,d\theta=\pi\, R$$

Comment: Excuse me for my illiteracy but why the first equalation  ($ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$) is correct?

Comment: futhermore: b. what is the different between $r^2$ and $R^2$ c.how did you get $ds=d\theta\sqrt{...}=Rd\theta$ (whats the connection between $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ and R?).

Comment: Check this pdf http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/footer/Courses/M111-112/Handouts/ArcLength112.pdf. If something is not clear I can help.

Comment: Some questions: a. how did you get to $ds=\sqrt{...}$ (what is the is the inﬁnitesimal Pythagorean theorem)? Drawing triangle as the picture for each invterval http://media.wiley.com/Lux/11/204911.image0.jpg? b.what is the meaning of $\int_C$? c.r is function of theta or a constant?

Comment: a. Yes. Check this website "derivation" section. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length

Comment: b. $\int_C$ means along the curve C. It is line integral http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral

Comment: thanks. Another question: when you derive and get $dx=cos(\theta)dr-rsin(\theta)d\theta$, how can you do that. I know that you can do $\frac{\partial {r}}{\partial x}  and derive at theta seperatly, which rule do you use?(I haven't studied it yet,still in improper integrals...)

Comment: Product rule http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule